Stopping scrolling animation on user click or touch | Javascript
I have this JS script:
function scrollToTop() {
const scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
if (scrollTop > 0) {
window.requestAnimationFrame(scrollToTop);
window.scrollTo(0, scrollTop - scrollTop / 8);
}
}

Works 'fine', nice smooth scrolling to top, but I need it to stop on user click,touch or even scrolling with its mouse.
The actual issue is that it won't stop til getting to top and sometimes the page gets stuck if the user do something before it finish scrolling to top, and have to reload.
Thanks!

I would suggest you add eventListeners that will cancel the scrolling animation when triggered by using a clause whether the animation should continue or not.
let isScrolling = true;

function scrollToTop() {
    const scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop || 
document.body.scrollTop;
    if (scrollTop > 0 && isScrolling) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(scrollToTop);
    window.scrollTo(0, scrollTop - scrollTop / 8);
}

}
function stopScrolling() {
    isScrolling = false;

}
scrollToTop();


window.addEventListener('scroll', stopScrolling);
window.addEventListener('click', stopScrolling);
window.addEventListener('touchstart', stopScrolling);

